# How to sign in case of using more then 1 certificate

Tags: cosign-api

I have more than 1 certificate, how to indicate the default one to use for signing in my SAPI code.
My code written in vb6.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to define a default certificate is by providing the serial ID of the preferred certificate as part of the configuration values (using [`ConfigurationValueSet`](http://docs.arx.com/sapi/Default.htm#doc/SAPIConfigurationValueSet.htm) SAPI function).

Another way to do it is to enumerate the certificates using [`CertificatesEnumInit`](http://docs.arx.com/sapi/Default.htm#doc/SAPICertificatesEnumInit.htm) and [`CertificatesEnumCont`](http://docs.arx.com/sapi/Default.htm#doc/SAPICertificatesEnumCont.htm) functions and then set the chosen one with the [`CertificateSetDefault`](http://docs.arx.com/sapi/Default.htm#doc/SAPICertificateSetDefault.htm) function.